# Performance issues AddControllers() vs AddControllersWithViews()

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. In `Program.cs`, I had `AddController()`, but I want to serve a html page on the root level `(https://localhost:{port}/)`.

I have created a view with the `index.cshtml`, and call that view through a controller. In order to use the `View()` method, I had to use `AddControllersWithViews()` instead.

My question: is there any drawback to using `AddControllersWithViews()` in an API with 50+ endpoints, where only **one** of them is requiring the view? Does it affect performance, stability, security or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

There is no major drawbacks using `AddControllersWithViews()` in project.`AddControllersWithViews()` in an ASP.NET Core project mainly affects the services that are added to the dependency injection container.

Regarding effect on performance, stability, security. there might minimal impact on the performance  unless you have a large number of concurrent requests. Both `AddControllers()` and `AddControllersWithViews()` are stable and have been widely used in various ASP.NET Core applications. There are no direct security implications of adding view support to an API project.

If you want to serve single html file it would be great if you use static files middleware UseStaticFiles().

Comment: Thank you! I use the View/Controller to send some data to the html-site, with @ViewBag etc. Do I have to use regular javascript to send data dynamically if I switch to UseStaticFiles(), or can I still use Razor-like code?

Comment: using `UseStaticFiles()`, you are serving static files directly without going through the MVC pipeline.If you are going to use `UseStaticFiles()`, you will need to serve a static HTML file, and then use JavaScript to fetch the dynamic data from your API and update the page.